# Is there a way in SharePoint online to programmatically find out how many users are assigned a SharePoint license in Office 365?

Tags: office-365, rest, licensing, office365apis

Basically we have a provider hosted app that needs to check the number of users in an Office 365 subscription that are assigned to a SharePoint license. Maybe some sort of Office 365 API?

Comment: It is part of the Graph API, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/11/14/announcing-the-new-version-of-the-graph-api-api-version-2013-11-08.aspx